# Upgrade Database Engine for AWS Hosted SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I cannot figure out how to upgrade an existing database in AWS from Microsoft SQL 14.xxx to 15.xxx. I was able to execute a minor upgrade within the 14.xxx family but the modify option does not have an option to do a major upgrade. Do I have to make a new instance, manually copy over all the settings, and then restore to that using a snap shot of the old instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[from the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.SQLServer.html)

> You can upgrade your existing DB instance to SQL Server 2017 from any version except SQL Server 2008. To upgrade from SQL Server 2008, first upgrade to one of the other versions.

there is no indication about upgrading MS SQL 2017 to 2019. I guess manuel migration will be best option (by backup and restore).